# mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts USE INDEX(abc) 
 WHERE a=3 and b=123 and c>4012 and d>5212300 and e!=661 
 LIMIT 10;
```

INDEX(abc) is an index of column a, b and c.

The query worked well until recently when the database gets big. It now has about 10million rows.

I have been trying to find alternatives to optimize it without much success. I hope someone can give me some clues. Thanks.

BTW, my table engine is innodb.

Comment: Can you give us some insight as to how these conditions are generated?

Comment: @Dan: adding d and e to index would be useless because it will have to do a full scan because the query for column c is not absolute.

Comment: @Sam: This query is to generate related posts, something like where category = 3, group = 123, domain > 4012, articleID > 5212300 and writer != 661.

Comment: Please post the result from EXPLAIN, and table structure as well

Comment: @Vern I may be wrong, but according to your explanation it seems that **b** is more unique in this table than **a**. So, if this is true then you may try index (b, a, c). By the way I would not be so confident that adding **d** to the index is useless because you are limiting the result to 10 rows only.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin my optimization by removing the **index hint** you are using. Query Optimizers do a pretty good job on guessing what's the best execution plan for your query, and providing index hints in the long run usually contribute negatively to query performance.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts 
 WHERE a=3 and b=123 and c>4012 and d>5212300 and e!=661 
 LIMIT 10;
```

I also think that independent indexes on columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` might help since the query planner will be able to combine indexes to resolve the query. (Not sure about MySQL but PostgreSQL would be able to combine them to resolve the query if it helps).

Comment: I don't think independent indexes can help. Check out this article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/

Comment: I just tried removing index hint. It's bad. All the queries suddenly jam up the process list. :(

Comment: @Vern: very interesting link indeed. Thanks a lot for sharing!